# Homepage Login form - Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have implemented a login form on my homepage of my site, however, when I go to login - it doesn't actually allow me to login. The end of my url after i select "LOGIN" says the following: "?username=admin&password=admin&submit=+"

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Primary Menu', 'container' => false,'menu_id' => 'main-nav','depth'=>'2')); ?>
            <div id="login" >
        <?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>               
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" style="padding-left: 2px;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="padding-left: 2px;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" " class="loginbutton" />
                </form>
                <a class="helpbutton" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <ul class="admin_box">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-admin/post-new.php">Write new Post</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?>">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        <?php }?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
/* Login
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#login {
    background-image:url(images/bluenavbg.png);
    height:39px;
    width: 370px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

form {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

input {
    background:url(images/formbg.png);
    width: 117px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border:none;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.loginbutton {
    height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background:url(images/loginbutton.png);
}
.helpbutton {
    height: 20px;
    width: 38px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background:url(images/helpbutton.png);
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: right;
}

#login ul {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 55px;
}

#login li a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are missing the action attribute to your form.

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">

        <input value="Username" class="input" type="text" size="20" tabindex="10" name="log" id="user_login" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Username') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" /> <input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90" type="checkbox"> Remember Me? <br />
        <input value="Password" class="input" type="password" size="20" tabindex="20" name="pwd" id="user_pass" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" />
        <input name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Log In" tabindex="100" type="submit">
        <input name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/" type="hidden">
        <input name="testcookie" value="1" type="hidden">

</form>
```

I've added it to your code below.

```
<div id="navbar">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Primary Menu', 'container' => false,'menu_id' => 'main-nav','depth'=>'2')); ?>
            <div id="login" >
        <?php if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){ ?>               
        <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">

            <input value="Username" class="input" type="text" size="20" tabindex="10" name="log" id="user_login" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Username') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Username';}" /> <input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90" type="checkbox"> Remember Me? <br />
            <input value="Password" class="input" type="password" size="20" tabindex="20" name="pwd" id="user_pass" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Password') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}" />
            <input name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Log In" tabindex="100" type="submit">
            <input name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/" type="hidden">
            <input name="testcookie" value="1" type="hidden">

    </form>
                <a class="helpbutton" href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <ul class="admin_box">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-admin/post-new.php">Write new Post</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?>">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        <?php }?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: hey this is great! Thanks! But is there anyway to instead of it going directly to the login page, can I just login directly from the login form which is on my homepage?

Comment: Find
`<input name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/" type="hidden">`

and replace it with

`<input name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/index.php" type="hidden">`

This will work however if the user inputs incorrect login details it will take them to wp-login.php

Comment: This worked! However, I have bridged Wordpress with vBulletin and since i've done that, it wont display what is supposed to be displayed after you log in. Is there anyone that can help with this - skype or something?

Comment: Sorry - not too sure I can help with that I'm afraid. Good luck!

Comment: @user1419405 Hi, if one of the answers helped you please vote it up and choose the best answer. Thank you :)